A low-rank approximation problem with rank constraints
I am seeking a solution or some ideas to address the following problem:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text { minimize }_{\widehat{A}, \widehat{B}} \quad\|A-\widehat{A}\|_2 + \|B-\widehat{B}\|_2 \\ &\text { subject to } \quad \operatorname{rank}([\widehat{A} \ \ \widehat{B}]) \leq r \text { and } \operatorname{rank}(\left[\begin{array}{c}
\widehat{A}  \\
\widehat{B}
\end{array}\right]) \leq r
\end{aligned}
$$
This problem is similar to the basic low-rank approximation problem, connected to the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem. However, the two conditions involved are challenging.
When considering the eigenvectors of matrices $A$ and $B$ independently, I was able to establish a loose upper bound of the minimum value, but further derivation becomes difficult.
I would appreciate any insights or approaches to tackle this problem.

the norm is spectral norm or Frobenius?

spectral norm, but both are ok
